# Add GitHub corner to xaringan title slide

Tags: css, xaringan

Is there a way to add a [GitHub corner](https://github.com/tholman/github-corners) or [GitHub ribbon](https://blog.github.com/2008-12-19-github-ribbons/) on the title slide for a Xaringan presentation using a CSS file?

I am able to add the code directly to the HTML file, but any the presentation is knitted the HTML is reconstructed. Ideally this would be a part of the CSS and controlled in the YAML, but I know very little about CSS/HTML/JavaScript.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can translate the HTML code into a CSS class you can set this class as a layout for all slides using `class: <class>`. YAML control will not be possible for such tasks. What is the problem with rebuilding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly mix HTML codes into the markdown source code. But to add github corner on the title slide, there's a bit of extra work required: turn off the auto-generated one and manually create it yourself:

1. Set `seal: false` in the YAML section to turn off auto-generated title slide.
2. Copy & paste HTML code for `github corner` or `github ribbon` into the markdown source file
3. setup the rest of the title slide.

Example ([I've also uploaded it on github](https://github.com/tcgriffith/cosx_exps/blob/master/test26.rmd)):

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
    seal: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

class: inverse, center, title-slide, middle

<style>
.title-slide .remark-slide-number {
  display: none;
}
</style>

# Presentation Ninja

## ⚔<br/>with xaringan

### Yihui Xie

### 2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)

<a href="https://your-url" class="github-corner" aria-label="View source on Github"><svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="fill:#fff; color:#151513; position: absolute; top: 0; border: 0; right: 0;" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M0,0 L115,115 L130,115 L142,142 L250,250 L250,0 Z"></path><path d="M128.3,109.0 C113.8,99.7 119.0,89.6 119.0,89.6 C122.0,82.7 120.5,78.6 120.5,78.6 C119.2,72.0 123.4,76.3 123.4,76.3 C127.3,80.9 125.5,87.3 125.5,87.3 C122.9,97.6 130.6,101.9 134.4,103.2" fill="currentColor" style="transform-origin: 130px 106px;" class="octo-arm"></path><path d="M115.0,115.0 C114.9,115.1 118.7,116.5 119.8,115.4 L133.7,101.6 C136.9,99.2 139.9,98.4 142.2,98.6 C133.8,88.0 127.5,74.4 143.8,58.0 C148.5,53.4 154.0,51.2 159.7,51.0 C160.3,49.4 163.2,43.6 171.4,40.1 C171.4,40.1 176.1,42.5 178.8,56.2 C183.1,58.6 187.2,61.8 190.9,65.4 C194.5,69.0 197.7,73.2 200.1,77.6 C213.8,80.2 216.3,84.9 216.3,84.9 C212.7,93.1 206.9,96.0 205.4,96.6 C205.1,102.4 203.0,107.8 198.3,112.5 C181.9,128.9 168.3,122.5 157.7,114.1 C157.9,116.9 156.7,120.9 152.7,124.9 L141.0,136.5 C139.8,137.7 141.6,141.9 141.8,141.8 Z" fill="currentColor" class="octo-body"></path></svg></a><style>.github-corner:hover .octo-arm{animation:octocat-wave 560ms ease-in-out}@keyframes octocat-wave{0%,100%{transform:rotate(0)}20%,60%{transform:rotate(-25deg)}40%,80%{transform:rotate(10deg)}}@media (max-width:500px){.github-corner:hover .octo-arm{animation:none}.github-corner .octo-arm{animation:octocat-wave 560ms ease-in-out}}</style>

<a href="https://github.com/you"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_left_white_ffffff.png" alt="Fork me on GitHub"></a>

---


# Slide 2

example xaringan slide for:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931518/add-github-corner-to-xaringan-title-slide
````

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18O3S.png)